# How do I remove hidden characters from a NSString?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

After copying pasting a text from the web, in my mac app NSTextArea, I see

```
EE
```

If I copy these 2 letters in a browser I see:

```
E?E
```

If I copy them in google translator I get

```
E 'E
```

I cannot identify this character in between the two E. But the question is: how do I remove these hidden characters from my NSString?

Comment: Could you upload a text file with the hidden characters in it somewhere so I can see what hex values are coming up as hidden?

Comment: @SomeGuy I've uploaded it here: http://cl.ly/text/1V2Y2A1l023d/hiddenText.txt

Comment: Concat it with `@"olly olly oxen free"` :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your uploaded file the specific hex code for the hidden character is 0x18

(found via Hex Fiend)

[image]

This character, along with others are part of a '[control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) set'. The set also contains characters such as the tab (0x09) and newline (0x0A) - obviously those we don't want to remove.

In Objective-C, we can use the NSCharacterSet *controlCharacterSet* in conjunction with *whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet* to get just the blank characters that have no rendered width.

```
NSMutableCharacterSet* zeroWidthCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[zeroWidthCharacterSet formIntersectionWithCharacterSet:[[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
```

Then we can simply use the good old split by character set method

```
string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:zeroWidthCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

<s>Note that if a special character that uses more than one UTF8 character to represent itself (like Emoji) uses 0x18 then stripping it will break the character combo</s>

Because the control characters are special, I don't believe you'd ever find them in an Emoji sequence.

Comment: Thanks, step forward. However, what I need is to just ignore all these hidden characters. A customer of mine copy pasted a text from the web. I need to clean all.

Comment: By the way: what kind of character is 0x18? I see it is associated to the "Cancel" key or "Control" key? I don't understand: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/18/index.htm

Comment: @Patrick I did some further research, that 0x18 is part of a control character set. I edited my answer with a full solution, although please do some thorough testing to make sure it doesn't remove anything you need :)